# Menu Responsivo

Tags: html, css

Fala galera, como eu posso esconder meu menu quando chegar na resolução 990?
o menu some o botão do toggle aparece mas quando clico nele não aparece o menu.

```css
.header_topo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 121px;
  background: red; }

.logo {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 100px;
  line-height: 100px; }

.layout_center {
  width: 100%; }

.wrap_menu {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 108px; }

.wrap_menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  listy-style: none; }

.wrap_menu li a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff; }

.btn-toggle {
  display: none; }

#navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block; }

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  #navbar {
    display: none; }

  .btn-toggle {
    display: block; } }
```

```html
<div class="layout_center">
  <div id="navbar" class="wrap_menu">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nossa empresa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn-toggle">Toggle</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Utilizando JavaScript

Para fazer aparecer com click, você consegue com javascript, segue abaixo um exemplo:

```js
function showMenu() {
  var $navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
  var style = window.getComputedStyle($navbar);
  
  if(style.display == 'none') {
    $navbar.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    $navbar.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.header_topo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 121px;
  background: red; }

.logo {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 100px;
  line-height: 100px; }

.layout_center {
  width: 100%; }

.wrap_menu {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 108px; }

.wrap_menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  listy-style: none; }

.wrap_menu li a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000; }

.btn-toggle {
  display: none; }

#navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block; }

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  #navbar {
    display: none; }

  .btn-toggle {
    display: block; } }
```

```html
<div class="layout_center">
  <div id="navbar" class="wrap_menu">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nossa empresa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="btn-toggle" onclick="showMenu()">Toggle</a>
</div>
```

---

### Utilizando CSS

Uma alternativa com css seria usando o `:focus`, mas para isso o html teria que ter uma pequena alteração, que é colocar o bottão "toggle" antes do menu. Mas esta solução não criaria exatamente o efeito toggle, e sim, quando clicar no botão ele abre o menu e quando clicar fora do botão ele fecha o menu:

```css
.header_topo {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 121px;
  background: red; }

.logo {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 100px;
  line-height: 100px; }

.layout_center {
  width: 100%; }

.wrap_menu {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 108px; }

.wrap_menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  listy-style: none; }

.wrap_menu li a {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000; }

.btn-toggle {
  display: none; }

#navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block; }

@media (max-width: 990px) {
  #navbar {
    display: none; }

  .btn-toggle {
    display: block; }
    
  .btn-toggle:focus + #navbar {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="layout_center">
  <a href="#" class="btn-toggle">Toggle</a>
  <div id="navbar" class="wrap_menu">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nossa empresa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fale Conosco</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A é verdade precisa do javascript, vlw Diego